# How to format SimpleIntegerProperty output

Tags: formatting, javafx-8

I do have a `SimpleIntegerProperty` which contains a number which is the time in 100ms steps like `40` is 4,0 seconds

I do want to display this value to the user with a `Label` which should display "4,0 s"

I would like to bind the value with the bindings api like

`label.textProperty().bind(myobject.secondsProperty().asString());`

but how do i create a simple and reusable Converter, i do need only the unidirectional binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [overloaded form of the `asString(...)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html#asString-java.lang.String-) that takes a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) as an argument:

```
String secondsFormat = "%.1f s" ;

label.textProperty().bind(myobject.secondsProperty().asString(secondsFormat));
```

If you really need a `StringConverter`, you can do

```
StringConverter<Integer> deciSecondsConverter = new StringConverter<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(Integer deciSeconds) {
        return String.format("%.1f s", deciSeconds.doubleValue()/10);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer fromString(String string) {
        // not implemented
        return null ;
    }
};
```

and then

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
    () -> deciSecondsConverter.toString(myobject.getSeconds()),
    myobject.secondsProperty()
));
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class StopwatchTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        IntegerProperty tenthsOfSeconds = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        Label label = new Label();
        StringConverter<Integer> deciSecondsConverter = new StringConverter<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Integer deciSeconds) {
                return String.format("%.1f s", deciSeconds.doubleValue()/10);
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {
                // not implemented
                return null ;
            }
        };

        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
            deciSecondsConverter.toString(tenthsOfSeconds.get()), 
            tenthsOfSeconds));

        new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                tenthsOfSeconds.set((int)System.currentTimeMillis() % 60000 / 100);
            }

        }.start();

        label.setPadding(new Insets(5, 20, 5, 20));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(label, 80, 30));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: That brought me on the right track, but since the value is an integer, the formatting by string does not work like this as `.1f` cannot be applied to int. You will have to do something like `this.label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createFloatBinding(()-> (float) myObject.getSeconds() / 10.0f, myObject.secondsProperty()).asString(secondsFormat));`

Comment: Probably better to fix the converter itself. See update.